# SWIG wrap const unsigned char example[] into a Java byte[] as argument

Tags: java, c++, c, swig

I have

const unsigned char publicKeyModulus[], and I would like to wrap it as an argument and get as a byte[] in my java layer.

c++
onInitialize(publicKeyModulus)

Java
onInitialize(byte[] publicKeyModulus)

SWIG.i

```
%typemap(jni) unsigned char *content "jbyteArray"
%typemap(jtype) unsigned char *content "byte[]"
%typemap(jstype) unsigned char *content "byte[]"
%typemap(javain) unsigned char *content {}

%typemap(in) unsigned char * content {
    $result = JCALL1(NewByteArray, jenv, arg1->contentLength);
    JCALL4(SetByteArrayRegion, jenv, $result, 0, arg1->contentLength, $1);
}

// Optional: ignore contentLength;
%ignore contentLength;

%inline %{
typedef struct {
    unsigned char * content;
    int contentLength;
} Foo;
%}
```

I've been trying a lot of variation of this swig files, as in the similar questions people is suggesting that, but it is not working for me. I guess because in the other question they use that as a return and I must be doing something wrong in my modifications to get it as an argument.

I would appreciate  your comments, thank you.

Comment: have you tried using `%apply` as described in [24.8.5 Binary data vs Strings](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Java.html#c_arrays)?

Comment: Yes I tried the apply, and it kind of give me back what I want. But it generates a GetByteArrayElements in the cxx file that makes my app crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a bunch of different solutions, the one that worked better was the %apply as suggested in one comment above.

```
%apply (char *STRING, size_t LENGTH) { (char *modulusBytes, int modulusLength) }
```

just a comment to highlight is that the name of the variables must be the same that the ones used in the declaration.